# How do I keep both version 8.0 and 5.1 of the MySQL ODBC connector?

Tags: mysql, windows-10, odbc, windows-server-2016, mysql-odbc-connector

I installed `MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.0` with the MSI installer on my development machine but it automatically uninstalled the `MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1` driver.

I reinstalled `MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1` with the MSI installer and both work in parallel now.

The server has both 5.1 and 3.51 versions of the ODBC driver.
I need to make sure that they are not uninstalled when installing version 8.0 on the server.

Any suggestions?

***Edit:** I ended up installing version 8.0 and then installing 5.1 again. Not ideal, but it worked.*